# Big query join on comma separated values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table structure in BigTable.

[image]

[image]

And I want below output by joining based on comma values.

[image]

MySQL has `find_in_set` function which does similar thing, but how can I do in bigquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider below option

```
#standardSQL
select id, product_name, 
  (select string_agg(category_name)
  from unnest(split(categories)) as cat_id
  join `project.dataset.categories` 
  on cat_id = cast(id as string)
  ) as categories
from `project.dataset.products`
```

for the sample data you provided in question - it returns

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string column, particularly when BQ has much better ways to store the data -- such as arrays.

You can do this -- by converting to arrays and back to strings:

```
select t.*,
       (select string_agg(c.category_name order by n, ',')
        from unnest(split(t.categories, ',')) category with offset n join
             categories c
             on category = c.id
       ) as categories
from t;
```

That said, you should at least use `array_agg()` for the results.